# how to write a validation rule that prevents users from entering any number starting in “07” in the contact phone field

Tags: validation

I want to prevent a user writing a number that begins with 07 in the phone field on the contact object

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Kal. Could you explain why this is difficulent to do for you and what you've tried to do so far ?

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to these salesforce articles with samples to understand how to build validation rules in general and for contact fields

[Sample Contact Validation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_contact.htm&language=en_US)

[Useful Validation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_useful_validation_formulas.pdf)

So for your case, you can try something simple

```
LEFT(Phone, 2) = "07"
```

but then you have to make sure about different formats that can be entered.. with country code.. with plus and braces + , ( ).. etc..